# How can I remove Social Engine header search field and button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm wondering if anyone with Social Engine code experience could tell me how to remove the global header search field and button?

I don't believe that it can be done via the Layout Editor.

I just need to know the path to the relevant file and what code to remove.